# Remove — before email signature in Thunderbird (MacOS)

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is it possible to remove the double dash (--) prior to an email signature in Thunderbird on MacOS?

I searched both here and around the web, and everything I found was very old and no longer useful. I really appreciate the help.

Thanks, Grant

Comment: Why would you to want to do that? Using `--<eol marker>` is the normal way of indicating a signature follows.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work:

#### Open the Config Editor

1. Open the preferences dialog (on the menu, it's either **Edit | Preferences** on Linux, or **Tools | Options** on Windows or **Thunderbird | Preferences** on Mac).

[image]

2. Select "Advanced" (right icon at the top - selected in the image I've attached here)
3. Click the "Config Editor" button.

#### Change the appropriate flag

1. In the config editor, type in the following:

   ```
   suppress_signature_separator
   ```

   you should see the (single) matching setting in the bottom part of the window.

[image]

2. Double-click the setting at the bottom part of the window. It will become boldfaced and change its value:

[image]

3. Restart Thunderbird (hopefully you don't actually need this, but let's be on the safe side)

Again, this *should* work but YMMV.